# How to show the title with qTip2 and jQuery with .hover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, qtip2

I am trying to set a title in my element at my JSP page using qTip2 and jQuery with a `.hover` function.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#send').qtip({
        content: {
            title: 'My Title'
        }
    });
});
```

the "send" is a button and I am trying to hover the mouse and get a message with the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer here.

Add the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.qtip.min.css">
```

Add the libraries:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('a');
    $('#send').qtip({ // Grab some elements to apply the tooltip to
      content: {
         text: 'My common piece of text here'
     }
    });  
});
```